# Issues with BPF filters and 6to4 traffic

Tags: tcpdump, pcap

I have a pcap file captured with tcpdump: `tcpdump -w out.pcap -ni eno1 host 192.88.99.1`

I can view the pcap:

```
rful011@secmonprd13:~$ tcpdump -nr out.pcap -tttt | head
reading from file andy.tcpd, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
2023-04-11 11:54:52.046310 IP 130.216.15.171 > 192.88.99.1: IP6 2002:82d8:fab::82d8:fab > 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301: ICMP6, echo request, seq 43217, length 8
2023-04-11 11:54:52.164305 IP 192.88.99.1 > 130.216.15.171: IP6 2002:c058:6301::1 > 2002:82d8:fab::82d8:fab: ICMP6, time exceeded in-transit for 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301, length 56
2023-04-11 11:54:52.165665 IP 130.216.15.171 > 192.88.99.1: IP6 2002:82d8:fab::82d8:fab > 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301: ICMP6, echo request, seq 43218, length 8
```

but any attempt to filter results in no output:

```
rful011@secmonprd13:~$ tcpdump -nr out.pcap -tttt ip6 net 2002::/16 | head
reading from file andy.tcpd, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
rful011@secmonprd13:~$
```

I came across while investigating why I was not seeing the 6to4 traffic in [Arkime](https://arkime.com/) -- in that case I had a bpf filter selecting `TCP` and this filtered out all 6to4 traffic.  Removing the `TCP` filter and Arkime logged the 6to4 traffic.

This issue seems to be with the libpcap? on my Ubuntu boxes *and* I get the same behaviour on my Mac!

I can see why filtering on any protocol would filter out 6to4 so how I can construct a bpf filter that will capture the 6to4 traffic while allowing me to filter other traffic normally.